# Angular reactive forms - forbid dangerous characters

Tags: angular, xss, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form, and I need to validate the free text fields for XSS. Should I use the DomSanitizer service before submitting to server, or should I use regex validator? and if I use a regex, which characters should I blacklist (or whitelist) exactly (I see many different patterns online). I presume that if I use DomSanitizer then I won't need to display a validation message to the user about unsafe characters, but I'm not sure that DomSanitizer was meant for that. What do you think?

Comment: What do you mean by "dangerous characters" or "unsafe characters"? `DomSanitizer` does not work at the level of individual characters, it strips whole semantic constructs from within a string, like style attributes or references to URLs. And that's not something regexes are well suited for accomplishing.

Answer (score 0):

Use Validation pattern to avoid characters which you may want to by showing error message to user.

[Reactive Forms Validation](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/reactive-forms-and-form-validation-with-angular-fdcbcf98e1e8)